# I can't find an answer to java.util.InputMismatchException

Tags: java

i have a question. When i run the code i get an error on the inputting the conversion rates. Could someone please help me in the right direction? I've copied part of the code and the error message.

Code:

```
public static void travelTimeAndBudget() {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many days are you going to spend travelling? ");
    int days = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("How much money, in USD, are you planning to spend on your trip? ");
    int usd = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("What is the three letter currency symbol for your travel destination? ");
    String currency = input.next();
    double currencyConvert;
    System.out.print("How many " + currency + " are there in 1 USD? ");
    currencyConvert = input.nextDouble();
    double currencyTotal = (currencyConvert * (double)usd);
    double currencyDay = (currencyTotal / (double)days);
    System.out.println("If you are travelling for " + days + " days that is the same as" + (days * 24) + " or " + (days * 360) + " minutes");
    System.out.println("If you are going to spend $" + usd + " USD that means per day you can spend up to $" + ((double)usd / days) + " USD");
    System.out.println("Your total budget in " + currency + " is " + currencyTotal + " " + currency + ", which per day is " + currencyDay + currency);
}
```

Output + error:

```
How many days are you going to spend travelling? 14
How much money, in USD, are you planning to spend on your trip? 2300
What is the three letter currency symbol for your travel destination? MXC
How many MXC are there in 1 USD? 19.8
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
    at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextDouble(Scanner.java:2564)
    at TripPlanner.travelTimeAndBudget(TripPlanner.java:33)
    at TripPlanner.main(TripPlanner.java:8)
```

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).useLocale(Locale.US);
```

Comment: I added this to my original scanner but now it's red and IntelliJ says: Cannot resolve symbol 'Locale'

Comment: You need to add `import java.util.Locale;`

Comment: Wow, that worked! Thank you so much! I still have no idea what Locale is (this is my first week in Java) but i'll look it up. Thank you again! Ok i googled it and i feel so stupid now... The course i'm following is from the US but i am from the EU. I was writing 19.8 when i should have just used 19,8.

Comment: You are Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

A useful tip for tracing bugs is to check the call stack. At the bottom of the error message you have:

at TripPlanner.travelTimeAndBudget(TripPlanner.java:33)
at TripPlanner.main(TripPlanner.java:8)

This tells you lines where your exception is being caught. Line 33 of TripPlanner.java is where to start debugging your code

Comment: Thank you for the help. At line 33 i have: currencyConvert = input.nextDouble(); so i know something is going wrong here. I input 19.8 but it gives the mismatch error. Isn't 19.8 a 'double' in Java?

Comment: For future reference you could add a try, catch block to your code so that you can handle the exception without it crashing your program.

Comment: Thank you, I've thought about doing something like if / else statements (from Python) but i'm on day 4 of Java now so i'll keep the try / catch in mind for when i run into something like this again.